# App crashes when all fields are empty and I click on pay button

Tags: android, kotlin

```
Exception dispatching input event
Exception in MessageQueue callback: 
handleReceiveCallback java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
  at com.fevziomurtekin.payview.Payview.checkAllFormFields(Payview.kt:532)
  at com.fevziomurtekin.payview.Payview.access$checkAllFormFields(Payview.kt:28)
  at com.fevziomurtekin.payview.Payview$initViews$6.onTouch
```

Comment: Seems like you'll have to validate the input… e.g. checking a `String` for emptiness before trying to convert it to an `int`.

Comment: "NumberFormatException: For input string: ''" is a Java error that occurs when you try to parse an empty string into a number. 

To handle this exception, you can check the input string before converting it into a number and make sure it's not empty.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.